# How to create ZIP file properly using zipfileset?

Tags: java, ant

I want to gather all `.map` files from Myproj directory also from it's sub-directories, then create a `L.zip` file.

Here is my code.

```
<target name="buildLFiles" >    
  <zip destfile="../../bin/L.zip" update="true" >
     <zipfileset casesensitive="no" dir="../../../Myproj" includes= "****/*.MAP" />
  </zip>
</target>
```

Problem here is, I am getting all `.map` files but it is getting created in file hierarchy wise.

#### Example:

This is original file structure:

```
MyProj  
 |- a  
    |- b   
       | - x1.MAP
```

Current Output:

```
L
|- a
   |- b 
      | - x1.MAP
```

Required output:

```
L
|- x1.MAP
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is flatten the structure using the copy task's `flatten` attribute in another directory, then zip that directory.

```
<target name="buildLFiles">
     <property name="tmp.dir" value="../../bin/TMP" />
     <property name="zip.file" value="../../bin/L.zip" />
     <copy todir="${tmp.dir}" flatten="true">
         <fileset dir="../../../Myproj">
             <include name="**/*.MAP" />
         </fileset>
     </copy>
     <zip destfile="${zip.file}" update="true">
         <zipfileset casesensitive="no" dir="${tmp.dir}" includes="*.MAP" />
     </zip>
     <delete dir="${tmp.dir}" />
</target>
```