# How to iterate through sub folder of sub folder to gather files?

Tags: java, ant

I have ABC main directory, in side that i have file structures like this, ABC->X(unkown sub directory)->Release>*.MAP X indicates all sub directories.

My question here is,How to iterate through all sub directories of ABC Folder and gather MAP files from release folder of that sub directories?

Pls help me

Comment: Can you please provide code what you have tried already?

Comment: in what way you want to achieve the iteration, java or ant ? please be specific while asking question

Comment: A java File object can be a File or a Directory. When it's a Directory (f.isDirectory()) you can use listFiles to get all nested files (which can be directories as well). Use recursion to find all files which match your criteria.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438789/how-to-create-zip-file-properly-using-zipfileset for your reference.                                   if you look at this code,it iterates through MyProj directory to gather all MAP files.                                                            But i need map files from MyProj->X(sub diractory may be many)->Release(constant) directory..                                            Below batch script i have written to do same  but i want to same in ant script                   FOR /d %%a in (*) DO .\Tools\zip -9 -j %ZIPDIR%\L%LEVEL% %%a\%CFG%\*.map

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include all sub-directories using ant `**` is what you're looking for. `**` matches **all**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438789/how-to-create-zip-file-properly-using-zipfileset for your reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438789/how-to-create-zip-file-properly-using-zipfileset for your reference.                                   if you look at this code,it iterates through MyProj directory to gather all MAP files.                                                            But i need map files from MyProj->X(sub diractory may be many)->Release(constant) directory..                                            Below batch script i have written to do same  but i want to same in ant script                   FOR /d %%a in (*) DO .\Tools\zip -9 -j %ZIPDIR%\L%LEVEL% %%a\%CFG%\*.map

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class. It has plenty of methods which might help achieve what you need.

Comment: <target name="buildLFiles">
     <property name="tmp.dir" value="../../bin/TMP" />
     <property name="zip.file" value="../../bin/L.zip" />
     <copy todir="${tmp.dir}" flatten="true">
         <fileset dir="../../../Myproj">
             <include name="**/*.MAP" />
         </fileset>
     </copy>
     <zip destfile="${zip.file}" update="true">
         <zipfileset casesensitive="no" dir="${tmp.dir}" includes="*.MAP" />
     </zip>
     <delete dir="${tmp.dir}" />
</target>  here Myproj is main directory,it has many sub directories and all these sub directories have folder called Release.

Comment: I want to copy all .map files from this release directories.             MyProj/**/Release/*.map How to achieve this in ant script?